# After adding Microsoft.Bcl.Async other projects don't recognize my dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asynchronous, .net-4.0, base-class-library

I'm developing an application with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

On a project I have to use async keyword. To do it I have added [Microsoft Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) nuget package.

After adding it, another projects that use this project return this message:

> C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3268: the main reference
>   "D:\MyProject\bin\x86\Release\MyProject.dll" could not be resolved
>   because it has an indirect dependency of the .NET Framework Assembly
>   "System.Runtime, Version = 1. 5. 11. 0, Culture = neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a" that could not be resolved in the
>   version of .NET Framework of current destination. ". NETFramework,
>   Version = v4. 0 ". To resolve this problem, remove the reference
>   "D:\MyProject\bin\x86\Release\MyProject.dll" or set the fate of the
>   application to a .NET Framework version containing "System.Runtime,
>   Version = 1. 5. 11. 0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken =
>   b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

And also another one about `"System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"`.

I have tried adding `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package to the other projects but I'm getting the same error.

Any idea about how to fix this issue?

I have followed what is said [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb/) (issue 6) (and also removing any version reference for those two dlls from csproj file) but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have KB2468871 update installed in your system? it is mentioned in the Nuget page.

Comment: Unless really necessary, you should now move to 4.5.2 and above. 4.0 is end of life.

Comment: @LexLi The main reason people target 4.0 is people are deploying to XP which does not support 4.5+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is add [Microsoft BCL Build Components](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build/1.0.21) to all the projects referencing the project that use Microsoft BCL Async.